# Como juntar essas duas querys em uma só?

Tags: mysql, query

Eu tenho uma tabela que registra as avaliações dos usuários em repostas de Fórum em rating, onde:
0 = Voto Negativo;
1 = Voto Positivo;
3 = Voto Anulado

[image: Tabela]

Se eu quiser pegar todos os votos em resposta de um unico usuario em um tópico eu faço o seguinte:

```
SELECT reply_id, rating 
FROM `forum_ratings` 
WHERE topic_id = '4' and user_id = '29'
```

Eu tenho outra query que pega todos os votos e agrupa por id da resposta, que no caso é o campo reply_id.

```
SELECT reply_id, 
sum(rating = '1') as likes, 
SUM(rating = '0') as unlikes 
FROM `forum_ratings` 
WHERE topic_id = '4' 
GROUP BY reply_id
```

Gostaria de agrupar e ao mesmo tempo ter o voto do usuario X na frente do resultado para cada reply_id. Sendo que se o usuario não votou nem positivo nem negativo em uma resposta seja mostrado o numero 3. Algo como:

```
reply_id    likes   unlikes current_user
6            234       12        0
7            122       44        1
8            14         5        3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo que um usuario tem apenas um voto por pergunta, pode fazer da seguinte forma, por exemplo:

```
SELECT A.reply_id, 
       SUM(case when A.rating = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as likes,
       SUM(case when A.rating = '0' then 1 else 0 end) as unlikes,
       MAX(COALESCE(CurrentUser.rating, 3)) as `current_user`
  FROM forum_ratings A
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT reply_id, rating FROM forum_ratings WHERE user_id = 29 
  ) AS CurrentUser 
    ON CurrentUser.reply_id = A.reply_id
 WHERE A.topic_id = '4' 
 GROUP BY A.reply_id
```

A função MAX é usada por causa da agregação que está a ser feita ao nível da resposta (reply_id). Neste caso, se o usuario com id = 29 tiver votado na resposta mostramos qual foi o voto (1, 2, ou 3). Caso contrário, mostramos 3.

Penso que esta alternativa também deve produzir o resultado esperado (deu o resultado correcto nos [poucos testes que eu fiz](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7940d1/6))

```
SELECT A.reply_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.rating = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as likes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.rating = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as unlikes,
       MIN(CASE WHEN A.user_id = 29 THEN a.rating ELSE 3 END) as `current_user`
  FROM forum_ratings A
 WHERE A.topic_id = '4' 
 GROUP BY A.reply_id
```

Comment: Eu usei o seu exemplo mas os resultados não foram corretos.

Comment: onde a nota do user id-1 foi 1 e a da user id-29,  o resultado da nota do user 29 foi 3

Comment: Se ele votou deveria ser 1 para positivo ou 2 para negativo, o que você propôs no código é exatamente o que eu quero. Depois de agrupar ter as notas de um único usuário em cada reply_id.

Comment: No seu exemplo, o usuario 29 apenas tem um registo com rating (3), pelo que assumi que para todas as respostas deveria mostrar 3.

Comment: Sim, neste caso está certo, mas quando a situação muda não dá certo. Como por exemplo se ele votou 1 ou 2, deveria mostrar 1 ou 2, mas está mostrando 3.

Comment: Esquecendo o exemplo acima. Imagine que só existem dois votos na reply_id = 4. O user_id_1 votou 1 e o user_id_2 votou 2. Quero o resultado com os votos do user_id_1, teria de retorna "1", mas retorna 3

Comment: Fiz o teste com a primeira qui e deu certo, só tive que alterar a paarte (bd.forum_ratings) para (forum_ratings); Mas até então tudo certo, vou testar com mais usuários aqui.

Comment: A segunda alternativa com o MIN parece dar o mesmo resultado e é mais concisa. Mas não tenho muita possibilidade de testar.

Comment: Testei aqui e tudo ok, vou mandar isso para o site kkk. Muito obrigado mesmo Bruno, vc é fera!

Comment: Não tem nada que agradecer. :)

Comment: vou testar com a segunda também, acha que ela tem melhor desempenho?

Comment: Eu diria que sim. Pois representaria apenas uma query direta na tabela forum_ratings. Para ter a certeza so mesmo vendo o plano de execução. Mas se a tabela não tiver muitos registos, não deve notar a diferença.